# Whenever I draw a shape, the transparency is 14%, how do I reset it to 100%?

Tags: after-effects

Whenever I draw a shape, the transparency is 14%, how do I reset it to 100%?
[image: Because every time I reset it and it annoys me]

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes make opacity 100%  than make another shape, that should do it.  But don't delete the current shape before make another one or problem will continue. Then you can delete both, enjoy your 100% opacity :)